# What format does the wxpython Image object expect for data when instantiating it using the wx.Image(width, height, data) constructor

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to generate an image by specifying each pixel. For this, I have written this little test to see how it works and apparently I am not using the right format for the data.

```
import numpy as np
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.SetSize(500, 500)
        self.SetTitle("Test")
    
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
    
        width = 500
        height = 500
    
        image_data = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(width, height, 3))
        print(image)
        image = wx.Image(width = width, height = height, data = image_data)
        bitmap = image.ConvertToBitmap()
    
        wx.StaticBitmap(panel, bitmap = bitmap, size = (500, 500))

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    window = Test(None, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
    print(type(window))
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code opens a window displaying a striped colorful image with black, red, blue and green pixels. Instead, I would have expected every pixel to be a random colour (not just red, blue and green) and far fewer pixels that are pitch black. The documentation on the wxpython site and on the original wxwidgets site only says that "data" ought to be in "RGB format" which I thought I had supplied with the method I use. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
[Example output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrmVT.png)

Comment: not too sure but most likely, `image = wx.Image(width = width, height = height)` overrides the previous image variable. I would rename that as `imagedata = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(width, height, 3))` and then use the imagedata in `image`

Comment: @macroland Thanks for the heads up. That was a mistake I made when I isolated the problem to post here. It has been fixed now. The problem sadly still persists.

Comment: try `size=(width*height*3)`, in the C++ documentation the data is `unsigned char *  data`, it is not clear in wxPython docs.

Comment: @macroland I have tried that just now and it results in the exact same behavior. I had a similar idea before, but nothing I tried in reformatting the image data has worked so far. I even have cast it into a bytes object and that did nothing to change the outcome thus far, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments has already mentioned, the documentation of wxwidgets in its original C implementation asks for an unsigned char array. In essence, the Image object expects its data in a format where every pixel is given by three bytes, each specifying the value of one of the channels of the RGB image.

As such, either a bytes object or for example a numpy array with datatype ubyte will work for this. Using int will result in the int being reinterpreted as separate bytes, which will result in the striped image shown in the original post.